# What is the type of arr in T(&arr)[N] here

Tags: c++, arrays

I came across this function below while learning about templates

```
template<typename T, int N>
int length(const T(&arr)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main(){
  int nums[]{1,2,3,4};
  int len = length(nums);
}
```

I used `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to understand what's going on, output is

```
int length(const T (&)[N]) [with T = int; int N = 4]
```

`const T (&)[N]` -> means type T array reference of size N?
What is the type of `arr` here?

Comment: Well, don't you already have the answer, a reference to an array of size N of T? Which part of that you're unsure about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the type of arr here?

It is `const T (&)[N]` i.e. reference to an array of N objects of type `const T`.

Note that this function template (or nearly identical) already exists in the standard library (by the name `std::size`), so there is no need to re-write it.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question, how is N deduced here? Should I ask it in different question?

Comment: @CPPnoob It is deduced from the argument.

Comment: so `nums` has size cached somehow, which is deduced by template? am I right?

Comment: `nums` is of type `int[4]`, and N is deduced from it right? I got confused, thinking `nums` is of type `int *`.

Comment: @CPPnoob that is why the reference is there. `T[N]` is castable to `T*` - but `T(&)[N]` is not.